# Why do fault simulation at RTL level?

Tags: simulation, fault, register-transfer-level

Why we do fault simulation at RTL level?

In recently, i am study fault simulation. I know fault simulation at gate-level, but i found that there exists some tools that support RTL level fault simulation, for example Z01X of Synopsys. Why need fault simulation at RTL level?

Answer (score 0):

RTL simulation is much faster and much easier to debug. You might want to do fault simulation at RTL level first to check that your safety mechanisms work fine and that you get desired fault coverage.